# Ruby regex unexpected result

Tags: ruby, regex

In this code,

```
"test bold bind abcd".scan(/\Ab.../) {|x| puts x}
```

I used `\A`, which indicates start of a string, then `b`, and three any characters. In my opinion, it should output:

```
bold
bind
```

but it outputs nothing. Can someone explain why this regex behaves different from what I expect?

Comment: “Start of a string” means _“start of a string”_, which is not a “start of word,” nor “start of something else.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start of your string is "test" so it doesnt match. You could use the word boundary operator:

```
/\bb.../
```

In case you weren't aware there is a neat tool to test regular expressions:

http://rubular.com/

A relevant quote from [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

> \A only ever matches at the start of the string. Likewise, \Z only
>   ever matches at the end of the string. These two tokens never match at
>   line breaks. This is true in all regex flavors discussed in this
>   tutorial, even when you turn on "multiline mode". In EditPad Pro and
>   PowerGREP, where the caret and dollar always match at the start and
>   end of lines, \A and \Z only match at the start and the end of the
>   entire file.